# Why did Rez want Ally to miss a couple of steps?

Tags: plot-explanation, a-star-is-born

In *A Star is Born*, Rez says to Singer Ally:

> Rez: You have to understand that this is what I do, and you have to
>   trust me, okay? So, if I give you a couple of dancers, don't not use
>   them and then **miss a couple of steps**, okay?

why did Rez want Ally to miss a couple of steps?

Comment: He meant that she missed a couple of steps because she didn't use the dancers - so he says if he gives her dancers, she should use them and don't miss a couple of steps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What he's saying is that the dancers help keep the visual rhythm.  Without the dancers, she missed a couple of steps of their choreography.  So that quote essentially means, "When I give you dancers to help with your visual cues, if you don't use them you're going to miss some of the cues and the choreography we practiced will go out the window."